# nudge a label on a time-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I would like to add and nudge a text label in ggplot, but nudge_x when x is POSIXct class does not change anything, no matter the value. Sample code here:

```
library(ggplot2)

start.time <- c("7:00", "8:00", "9:30")
end.time <- c("10:00", "11:00", "13:30")
market <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")

df <- data.frame(market, start.time, end.time)

df$start.time <- as.POSIXct(df$start.time, format="%H:%M")
df$end.time <- as.POSIXct(df$end.time, format="%H:%M")
df$length <- df$end.time - df$start.time


ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start.time, xend = end.time, 
               y = market, yend = market), 
           color = "darkgreen", size = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = min(start.time), y = market, label = length), 
        hjust = 0, size = 3, color = "darkgreen", nudge_x = -1)
```

Creates this image:

[image: test plot]

I would like the labels for the length of the lines to be further to the left. I do not think nudge_x = -1 is registering because it is not the correct class.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just add `x = min(start.time) - 300` for instance. Or an other duration to shift as much as you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On datetime scale nudge_x=-1 shifts to left by 1 sec, which is not visible, may be you want to nudge by 1 hr (3600 secs):

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start.time, xend = end.time, 
                   y = market, yend = market), 
               color = "darkgreen", size = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = min(start.time), y = market, label = length), 
            hjust = 0, size = 3, color = "darkgreen", nudge_x = -3600)
```

[image]

To nudge by 15 mins use to `nudge_x = -15*60`

Comment: thanks! this worked. i should've realized units were in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

As another option, you could put the labels inside the segments. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start.time, xend = end.time, 
                            y = market, yend = market), 
               color = "darkgreen", size = 5) +
  geom_text(data=df %>% group_by(market) %>% 
              summarise(xval=mean(c(end.time, start.time)),
                        length=paste(length, "hours")),
            aes(x = xval, y = market, label = length), 
            size = 3, color = "white") + 
  labs(x="Time") + theme_bw()
```

[image]